# Error initializing the InputInjector in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm using `InputInjector` to simulate a mouse click on a UI element in my custom `UWP` control (which is included into a `WPF` application using `XamlHost`). I implemented based on [this](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2018/01/injecting-input-in-uwp-apps/) article. It works fine on my PC, but on another PC can't create the Input Injector instance. When the `InputInjector.TryCreate();` is called, it throws the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010117): Call context cannot be accessed after call completed. (0x80010117)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
   at Windows.UI.Input.Preview.Injection.InputInjector.TryCreate()
   at >MyMethod()<
```

What this exactly mean? I tried to run this function on UI and background threads as well, but both fails. What could be the issue?

**Update:**

The other PC's OS version is 1909 (build 18363.1316), my PC's version is newer: 2004. As I see the InputInjector was introduced in 10.0.14393.0

Comment: Could you share more info about the other pc's OS version ?

Comment: Have you tested with any other pc ?

Comment: We can't reproduce your problem, and it looks is the os problem, could you try to update the pc OS?

Comment: Ok, I will post answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error initializing the InputInjector in UWP

During the testing, we can't reproduce your problem, and it looks is the OS problem, and you  could you try to update the pc OS to latest version. And test again, it works fine within my environment(the newest version).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, updating the windows solved the issue.